# Laravel forge - how multiple servers could access same database

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I use Laravel Forge to deploy 2 web apps to the same VPC in AWS like following:

A server ( with MySQL installed ):
 - domain: test-erp.foo.com
 - ip: 3.112.70.152

B server:
 - domain: test.foo.com
 - ip: 13.230.27.11

I can access MySQL in A server, but I can not access the MySQL from B server. I need both two web apps to access the same DB and how can I config it in Laravel forge ?

Comment: I think you can create a network inside Forge and connect with the private IP address, not 100% sure tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a security group for that VPC and a rule that allows the traffic that is needed. For [reference](https://serverfault.com/questions/830239/connecting-to-an-rds-from-an-ec2-on-the-same-vpc).